# How to create a microshell in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, shell, unix, pid

I have an assignment to "Create a microshell in C/C++" and I am trying to figure out what exactly that means.  I have this C code so far:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

int main(void)
{

char buf[1024];
pid_t pid;
int status;
printf("%% ");

while (fgets(buf,1024,stdin) != NULL)
{

    buf[strlen(buf) -1] =0; //remove the last character. Important!

    if ((pid = fork()) <0)
            printf("fork error");
    else if (pid==0)
    {       /* child */
            execlp(buf, buf, (char *) 0);
            printf("couldn't execute: %s", buf);

            exit(127);
    }//else if end

    /* parent */
    if ( (pid = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) <0)
            printf("waitpid error");

    printf("%% ");
}//while end

exit(0);
}//main end
```

I need to be able to invoke it using just it's name.  So the name of my program is prgm4.cpp, so I need to be able to do this:

```
%>prgm4
prgm4>(user enters command here)
```

What do I need to add to my code to be able to do this?  Also, how would I alter this to accept a command with two words, such as cat file.txt?  Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: You should focus on receiving input before executing stuff.

Comment: Does the command need to handle spaces correctly?  For example, does it need to correctly read `cat "file with spaces.txt"`?

Comment: no spaces in the file name, though I will eventually have to use pipe() somehow to use "||" as the pipe in my program. I am more worried about how to invoke my program from the commandline though using just it's name.  I think this means making my C++ program into a shell?

Comment: Some style points: don't use fixed length buffers - ever; `return 0` instead of `exit(0)`; use C or C++, not both; use C++; use `iostream` instead of `f*`; use `std::getline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're just asking how to run your program with it's name, rather than with a full path to the file.

```
$ prgm4 # You want this...
$ /path/to/my/program/prgm4 # ...Instead of this.
```

If that's the case, it doesn't have anything to do with the program itself.  You need to  move your program to a place that's in the [`$PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_variable) variable, like /usr/bin on Linux, or edit the PATH variable to include the directory it's already in.   For example:

```
$ PATH="/path/to/my/program:$PATH"
```

See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them/284351#284351) Super User question for more details.

Comment: Yup, thanks! The word "microshell" was just confusing me, now I see how to do this. Do you know what I need to do to accept a command with a space in it?  Like "cat file.txt"? Thank you!!

Comment: I think he might be asking how to get the compiler to use his name, and not just producing "a.out", but I could be wrong there.

Comment: for spaces you can use popen or system instead of an exec* to run the command with quotes around arguments with spaces (if it is always going to be on a posix system, then probably popen)